# PHP code does not work. Simple code but I am stuck

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

My PHP code gives an error.
My idea was to just check if the username and password exists in the database and then redirect it to the URL.

enter code hereI have two pages created. One is index and other is redirect.
Redirect code is giving problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
//echo $_POST['uname'];
//echo $_REQUEST['uname'];
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
//echo $_POST['pwd'];
//echo $_REQUEST['pwd'];
//echo $uname;
//echo $pwd;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db_found=mysql_select_db("sn", $con);  

 //$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname,password FROM udata");

if ($db_found) 
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname,password FROM udata");
while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
{
if ($db_field['uname']==$uname && $db_field['password']==$pwd)
header( 'Location: www.youtube.com' ) ;

/*print $db_field['fname'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['lname'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['uname'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['password'] . "<BR>";
*/
}

mysql_close($con);

}
else 
{

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);


}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the error? [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You failed to give us the exact error you are experiencing, and both ends of the code.

Comment: many many examples of poor practice here, particularly with the password handling. And use of the `mysql_xx()` functions is a bad sign too. If you're just learning PHP, please find a better and more up-to-date source of tutorials than the ones you're using now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change this:

```
if ($db_field['uname']==$uname && $db_field['password']==$pwd)
```

to this:

```
if ($db_field['fname']==$uname && $db_field['password']==$pwd)
```

Comment: Nice catch! I had to read your answer a couple of times before I saw it

Comment: I don't see any difference :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of errors. Properly indenting it should show some missing opening/closing braces: you should be able to find them yourself!

---

Furthermore, you directly start to output the HTML page. But, later on you use

```
header( 'Location: www.youtube.com' ) ;
```

if the username and password are correct to redirect the browser to another page. You *cannot* send HTTP headers after you started to output the HTML page already (without some advanced tricks)

---

After the redirect you need to stop the program flow (as it does not matter anymore) using `exit()`.

---

Assuming you have multiple users in your `udata` table, you need to add search conditions to the query. There are many possibilities, this is one:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM udata WHERE fname='$uname'");
```

Now you can check if this returned a record (if not the user does not exist) and whether the password is correct.

Note: directly using the `$_POST[]` values makes your application vulnerable SQL injection attacks (amongst others). You need to sanitize these inputs.

Additional note/pro-tip: Directly stores passwords in your database is a bad-thing(tm). Instead use hashes and salt (look it up with your [favorite search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+password+hash+salt))

---

As already commented by [njk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679449/njk) you should not use the depreciated `mysql_*` functions anymore.

Comment: I think I got most of the problematic areas... Now it is up to you to fix them!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of `{` and you should add `exit();` after your `header('Location: www.youtube.com');`

```
<?php
    $uname=$_POST['uname'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_found=mysql_select_db("sn", $con);  


    if ($db_found) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT fname,password FROM udata");
        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            if ($db_field['fname']==$uname && $db_field['password']==$pwd) {
               header('Location: www.youtube.com');
               exit();
            }
        }

        mysql_close($con);

    } else {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
?>
```